# Is it safe to remove "rdmgrab" in Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave

I recently upgraded to Mojave. So far I haven't had any problems with it. However, when I restart the Mac, I get a pop-up saying '“rdmgrab” is not optimised for your Mac and needs to be updated.'

There is a process called rdmgrab that runs in the background. (There's another called rdmd, but I don't know if it's related.)

There is a file called rdmgrab in `/opt/local/bin,` a `rdmgrab.plist` and a few `rdmgrab_[1811xx].log` files.

I have no idea where this file came from. Does anyone have an idea what it might be, and whether it's safe to dump it?

Comment: You can try renaming it before deleting it.    Anything in /opt directory is add-on software.

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit of searching on this. I don't suppose you have TeamViewer, LogMeIn, VNC or another remote viewer installed? Chrome desktop anywhere?

This could be related to that?

See this other stack exchange post:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71344/strange-tcp-traffic-on-mac-os-x-from-rdmd

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Thanks. I do use VNC, but not the others. But I renamed both rdmgrab and rdmd, and VNC seems to be working.